# RTF template Pagetotal + Brought/Carried Forward

Tags: rtf, obiee, bi-publisher

Please help me to achieve the below in RTF template .

page total+ brought forward at each page header.

page total+ carry forward at each page footer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHJMb.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SziiS.png)

We have tried with the help of below oracle document but still helping.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E80149_01/bip/BIPRD/GUID-048C89F1-CFF6-48B3-9175-8C5A68167D15.htm#BIPRD2504

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Ana, As per above oracle doc we could get page total and Brought/Carry Forward. But i have a requirement to page total+brought forward at each page header level and page total+ carry forward at each page footer level.